Excel VBA not copying over strings
I am running some simple, easy-to-automate transactions in SAP using an Excel macro to drive it. It's pretty much just copying a sales order number from a very long list into a specific field, clicking some buttons, and then copying the resulting contract number generated back into the list in the Excel file.
Whenever it runs into an error or takes a particularly long time, when it starts the next loop it won't copy over the sales order number from the Excel file unless I enter a stop line - it will only copy it over when I am somewhat involved, and I would prefer to just start it and let it run without babysitting it.
Sometimes the transactions will give other results than spitting out a contract number, which is why there are some extra stuff, but the important part is the part towards the beginning of the loop pointed out with asterisks. Is there something I'm doing wrong in the loop? It almost feels like it's just trying to click buttons too fast so I tried adding wait and sleep lines but it still wouldn't fill out the field - just run right through the line.
Worth mentioning, just hitting F5 whenever it stops is enough for the code to copy over the data. Without the stops it won't copy it, but when it stops it will copy it over. Any help is greatly appreciated as I have 2000 of these to go through and I would really love to just let this run overnight for a few days.
I have tried both wait and sleep lines, thinking that it just needed more time. I even tried putting the same two lines (wait, copy, wait, copy) just to make sure, to no avail. It just hit enter without entering anything in the field, which led to it hanging trying to grab everything from that year.
Sub ContractMacro()

Dim MyApplication As SAPFEWSELib.GuiApplication
Dim Connection As SAPFEWSELib.GuiConnection
Dim session As SAPFEWSELib.GuiSession
Dim SapGuiAuto As Object
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim currentso As Range
Dim contractrng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim x As Integer

Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI").getscriptingengine
Set objGui = SapGuiAuto.getscriptingengine
Set objConn = objGui.Children(0)
Set session = objConn.Children(0)
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Set contractrng = Range("A2:A" & WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")))
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_FKDAT-LOW").Text = "01.01." & Year(Date) - 1
For Each cell In contractrng
'    If Now >= Range("C4") And Now >= Range("C2") Then
'        Exit Sub
'    Else
'    End If
2
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_FKDAT-LOW").Text = "01.01." & Year(Date) - 1
    x = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B:B")) + 1
    Set currentso = Cells(x, 1)
    If currentso = "" Then
        GoTo 4
    End If
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_AUBEL-LOW").Text = currentso
'************* line above does not carry over currentso************************ 
    If session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_AUBEL-LOW").Text = "" Then
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_AUBEL-LOW").Text = currentso
    Stop
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_AUBEL-LOW").Text = currentso
    Stop
    Else
    End If
'************** if statement above was added to manually make sure it's copied over***********
    On Error GoTo 3
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
    Select Case session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell").GetCellValue(0, "STATUS")
        Case Is = "A"
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell").setCurrentCell -1, ""
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell").SelectAll
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell").PressToolbarButton "ZIH20"
            session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell").setCurrentCell -1, ""
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell").SelectAll
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell").PressToolbarButton "VFLG"
            Cells(currentso.Row, 2) = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell").GetCellValue(0, "SDAUFNR")
            session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
            session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
            session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
        Case Else
            Cells(currentso.Row, 2) = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell").GetCellValue(0, "STATUS")
            session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
    End Select
    wb.Save
Next cell
4
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Exit Sub

3
On Error GoTo -1
On Error Resume Next
Cells(currentso.Row, 2) = Trim(session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtMESSTXT1").Text)
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/N ZI_EW2_CONTROL"
session.findById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 0
GoTo 2
End Sub



What specific errors are you getting?

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Found the solution! Rather than just referencing the currentso range, I changed it to currentso.text.
If anyone else is running into data not copying into something in SAP, try that!
